# What is wrong with the requirement of writing pathways to impact in an EPSRC grant proposal?

Tags: research-process, career-path, funding

By definition, an academic scientist is supposed to do research and teaching. His main job should be to create knowledge and explore the unknowns, and to teach our kids so that the knowledge and capacity of creating knowledge will be inherited.

In my opinion, it is not his job to do outreach or to think about how to realize the societal impact of his research. That is supposed to be the job of entrepreneurs and politicians!

Asking a researcher to spread his already tight time on such things does no good but harm. Therefore any grant agencies (e.g. the UK EPSRC) should be prevented from asking a researcher to write something like 'pathways to impact' in his grant proposals. This is completely outside his expertise. It only wastes the time and distracts his mind.

How would you think? If you agree, what do you think can be possibly done to change this situation?

P.S. I'm not saying a researcher should not do outreach. I'm saying he should not be forced to do that. It is not his main job. Whether doing outreach or not should not result in any pressure on them concentrating on their main job. I suppose this is expected for any healthy profession.

Comment: This question is presented in such a way as to make it entirely a matter of opinion, not evidence or experience: "In my opinion", "How would you think?", etc. This site is for sharing information and explanations about academia, not debating the role of academics in society (see the [help/dont-ask]). If you can [edit] this question and reframe it so as to be more objective, then perhaps it may be reopened.